# If we know $x^T A x$ for all vectors $x$, can we solve for the matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a symmetric $n\times n$ real matrix. Suppose we do not know what $A$ is, but we have access to the values of $x^TAx$ for all vectors $x\in\mathbb R^n$. Can we determine $A$ from this information?

If the answer is yes, I would also like to know explicit formulas to obtain the elements of $A$.

It is easy to get the diagonal elements of $A$, by using $x=e_i$, where $e_i$ is the cartesian unit vector in the $i$'th direction. Then $A_{ii}=e_i^TAe_i$. But I'm not sure how to get the non-diagonal elements.

Comment: How far have you got? Do you see how to get $a_{11}$ for example? What about $a_{12}$?

Comment: @almagest Yes, $a_{11}$ is easy. But I'm not sure about the non-diagonal elements. Please note that this is not homework. If you have an answer I'd like to see it.

Comment: Well, the hint is that the matrix is symmetric, ie $a_{12}=a_{21}$. The whole point about math is that it is not a spectator sport. You don't get anywhere unless you make a significant effort to do things without help. They always look easy when others show you how, but hard when you try on your own!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: Once you know the diagonal elements, consider $x=e_i+e_j$.

Comment: Thanks. I see now that the non-diagonal elements are determined and I see how to construct a recursive scheme to find them all. Is there a way to arrive at a closed formula?

Comment: It seems like a closed formula to me when you write this out explicitly. I don't see why you need recursion.

Comment: Oh sorry, I got confused there. You are right. $2a_{ij}=(e_i^T+e_j^T)A(e_i+e_j) - e_i^TAe_i - e_j^TAe_j$ is perfectly closed.